# Getting different SQL results when I feel like it should be the same

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

So I have a query that I'm trying to run. Right now it's running through a loop in my code and doing a select on each neighbourhood ID. I would rather it do a single select and just loop through those results as that's WAY less of a hit on the DB imho. Anyway, I can't figure out why these two queries are giving me different results:

First Query:

```
SELECT `neighbourhood_id`,
    SUM(IF(`c`.`listing_offer` = 1, 1, 0)) as `listing_for_sale`,
    AVG(IF(`c`.`listing_offer` = 1, `price`, 0)) as `avg_sale_price`,
    SUM(IF(`c`.`listing_offer` = 2, 1, 0)) as `listing_for_rent`,
    AVG(IF(`c`.`listing_offer` = 2, `price`, 0)) as `avg_rent_price`
FROM (
    SELECT `n`.`id` AS `neighbourhood_id`, `l`.*
    FROM `listing` `l`
        LEFT JOIN `address` `a` ON `l`.`address_id` = `a`.`id` 
        LEFT JOIN `address_neighbourhood` `an` ON `a`.`id` = `an`.`address_id` 
        LEFT JOIN `neighbourhood` `n` ON `an`.`neighbourhood_id` = `n`.`id` 
        WHERE (`l`.`deleted`=0) 
            AND `n`.`id` IS NOT NULL
            AND `n`.`id` = 1
        GROUP BY `l`.`id`
    ) `c`
GROUP BY `neighbourhood_id`
```

Result:

```
neighbourhood_id    listing_for_sale    avg_sale_price  listing_for_rent    avg_rent_price
1                   7541                486634.853967   4045                786.372706
```

Second Query:

```
SELECT `neighbourhood_id`,
    SUM(IF(`c`.`listing_offer` = 1, 1, 0)) as `listing_for_sale`,
    AVG(IF(`c`.`listing_offer` = 1, `price`, 0)) as `avg_sale_price`,
    SUM(IF(`c`.`listing_offer` = 2, 1, 0)) as `listing_for_rent`,
    AVG(IF(`c`.`listing_offer` = 2, `price`, 0)) as `avg_rent_price`
FROM (
    SELECT `n`.`id` AS `neighbourhood_id`, `l`.*
    FROM `listing` `l`
        LEFT JOIN `address` `a` ON `l`.`address_id` = `a`.`id` 
        LEFT JOIN `address_neighbourhood` `an` ON `a`.`id` = `an`.`address_id` 
        LEFT JOIN `neighbourhood` `n` ON `an`.`neighbourhood_id` = `n`.`id` 
        WHERE (`l`.`deleted`=0) 
            AND `n`.`id` IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY `l`.`id`
    ) `c`
WHERE `neighbourhood_id` = 1
GROUP BY `neighbourhood_id`
```

Result:

```
neighbourhood_id    listing_for_sale    avg_sale_price  listing_for_rent    avg_rent_price  
1                   5740                522544.830430   2870                762.646690
```

I'm pretty sure query 1 is the correct result, so I'm not sure why I'm getting different results on the second query. I stand to be corrected though in terms of which one is the correct one.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: the inner "GROUP BY" in the second case may be grouping rows which do have neighbourhood=1 & also some other value & returning one of the other values as neighbourhood in the result of the select.

Comment: In 1st query is _"AND `n`.`id` IS NOT NULL"_ necessary as the next part of the clause is  _"AND `n`.`id` = 1"_ which are mutually exclusive

Comment: @PaulF the `IS NOT NULL` is there because I would like to remove the ` n.id=1` and get the results for all neighbourhoods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First group by is used then where condition is filters the record sets. Now the key is It is not necessary that group by maintain order. Your both query's sub query have return results in different order and after that where creates problems for filter.**

The condition is  `AND`neighbourhood`.`id`= 1` in where clause of Form Subquery `'c'` in first query where this condition is in main query's Where clause. This means in second query's subquery c 's record sets which can have  `neighbourhood`.`id` values other than 1 and after that group by used which takes any record whose value can be any thing from that record set. But in first subquery only those record sets are selected where `neighbourhood`.`id`=1`e`and group by results a record which can have the`value neighbourhood`.`id`=1.

for example
your second query's subquery c have select a record with `n.id = 0` but this record will be rejected and not used in outer query because where `n.id=1` is testing, So inner query result is not used. But in first query 's subquery c will select those records which `n.id=1` and it will always used in outer query. Hence both results differs.

suppose the  subquery c  is -

```
SELECT `l`.`id` , `n`.id
    FROM `listing` `l`
        LEFT JOIN `address` `a` ON `l`.`address_id` = `a`.`id` 
        LEFT JOIN `address_neighbourhood` `an` ON `a`.`id` = `an`.`address_id` 
        LEFT JOIN `neighbourhood` `n` ON `an`.`neighbourhood_id` = `n`.`id` 
        WHERE (`l`.`deleted`=0) 
            AND `n`.`id` IS NOT NULL;
```

is results-

```
(l.id , n.id) (1,0),(1,1)
```

when group by is used it return-

```
(l.id , n.id) (1,0)
```

and this record is not used in outer query.

but in first query the subquery the result would be

```
(l.id , n.id) (1,1)
```

and it is used in outer query.

Comment: I still don't quite understand. In the first query, the inner select is only selecting records with `n.id = 1`, so the outer query doesn't have discard anything. With the second query, it selects all records, but the outer query then discards all records that aren't `n.id = 1`. In my mind this is the same, the first it filters/discards in the inner query and the second it does it on the outer query. I think I'm misunderstanding some fundamental here

Comment: @SynackSA i have set up example

Comment: Your comment made me go back and look at my data and WHY the statement was grouping by `l.id`. My `address_neighbourhood` table had A LOT of duplicate data. I fixed up the table and data and it made my life a lot easier, so much so that I can do what I want to do in a single query now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you were trying to do too much at once. You don't want the group by listing ID (I don't think you do, if so you need to use aggregates inside the innermost query). I believe this is what you really need (note the aggregates are all SUMs):

```
select `neighbourhood_id`, 
    `listing_for_sale`, `total_sale_price` / `listing_for_sale` as `avg_sale_price`,
    `listing_for_rent`, `total_rent_price` / `listing_for_rent` as `avg_rent_price` from
    (SELECT `neighbourhood_id`,
        SUM(IF(`c`.`listing_offer` = 1, 1, 0)) as `listing_for_sale`,
        SUM(IF(`c`.`listing_offer` = 1, `price`, 0)) as `total_sale_price`,
        SUM(IF(`c`.`listing_offer` = 2, 1, 0)) as `listing_for_rent`,
        SUM(IF(`c`.`listing_offer` = 2, `price`, 0)) as `total_rent_price`
    FROM (
        SELECT `n`.`id` AS `neighbourhood_id`, `l`.*
        FROM `listing` `l`
         LEFT JOIN `address` `a` ON `l`.`address_id` = `a`.`id` 
         LEFT JOIN `address_neighbourhood` `an` ON `a`.`id` = `an`.`address_id` 
         LEFT JOIN `neighbourhood` `n` ON `an`.`neighbourhood_id` =        `n`.`id` 
        WHERE (`l`.`deleted`=0) 
         AND `n`.`id` IS NOT NULL
    ) `c`
  GROUP BY `neighbourhood_id`
) `d`
```